# Overriding active-record attributes method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wanted to overwrite the default active-record `attributes` method because i dont want to return `created_at` and `updated_at` in my json responses of any model.

so here's what i have done.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def attributes
    super.except('created_at', 'updated_at')
  end
end
```

This worked fine for me for the past few months. But now i came across a scenario that i should not send the `password` attribute from my `User` model. So

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def attributes
    super.except('password')
  end
end
```

This worked like a charm when i run it from rails console. But when i run it from a controller, i really don't know for what reason, but it goes for a infinite loop. And here is my controller action.

```
def update
  @object = klass.find(id)
  @object.update_attributes!(update_params)
  render json: {
    status: true,
    message: 'Saved Successfully..!',
    data: object_json(@object)
  }
end

def object_json(object)
  object.as_json.except('updated_at', 'created_at')
end
```

Can someone help me out of this.

Comment: I have to ask why you're overriding such a fundamental ActiveRecord method just to leave a couple things out of your JSON. Wouldn't a more targeted solution be better?  `as_json` takes an `:except` option to leave some attributes out. You could also use something like Jbuilder to separate your internal structure from your JSON.

Comment: Yes. There are more better options out there, but i chose this because i didn't see anything potentially wrong in this approach. Now i wanna know why this piece of code goes for a toss on the controller, when it works fine on a console. Any idea? @muistooshort

Comment: And i wanna apply this logic throughout my models, so i have to override a default method somewhere to apply this patch. Correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to control what attributes you want to render in your JSON responses, is to use a serializer like for example [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable)

A good article to read about it can be found here [SERVING CUSTOM JSON](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/active-model-serializers)

I wouldn't recommend overwriting default active-record `attributes` method